# SQL More complex than "Group by top n", I think

Tags: sql, h2

I apologize if my answer is posted elsewhere, but I have searched and am unable to find it. I am trying to accomplish the following in SQL (with H2):
Here is a query that works:

```
SELECT
  t38.patient_id,
  t38.id AS t38id,
  t38.effective_time_start AS t38ets,
  t38.effective_time_end AS t38ete,
  t36.id AS t36id,
  t36.effective_time_start AS t36ets,
  t36.effective_time_end AS t36ete
FROM View1 AS t38
INNER JOIN View2 AS t36
  ON t38.patient_id = t36.patient_id
  AND t36.effective_time_start < t38.effective_time_start
```

What I need it to do is have a `max` on `t36.effective_time_start` and a group by `t38.id`, like so:

```
SELECT
  t38.patient_id,
  t38.id AS t38id,
  t38.effective_time_start AS t38ets,
  t38.effective_time_end AS t38ete,
  t36.id AS t36id,
  MAX(t36.effective_time_start) AS t36ets,
  t36.effective_time_end AS t36ete
FROM View1 AS t38
INNER JOIN View2 AS t36
  ON t38.patient_id = t36.patient_id
  AND t36.effective_time_start < t38.effective_time_start
GROUP BY t38.id
```

This does not work.

Here is what I’m trying to accomplish:
For each patient ID, I have a set of t38s and t36s. I want all the data about them, joined together, but I only want rows where t36 starts before t38. I also only want one row per t38id, and that row needs to be the most recent (max start time) t36, but it can't be just max, it has to still be prior to the t38 start time.

`DISTINCT ON` and `RANK ON PARTITION` are both approaches I can’t try as they are not supported in H2. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with your data but would something along the lines of the following work? (may require some tweaking to achieve desired results)

```
SELECT t38.patient_id,
t38.id AS t38id,
t38.effective_time_start AS t38ets,
t38.effective_time_end AS t38ete,
t36.id AS t36id,
t36.effective_time_start AS t36ets,
t36.effective_time_end AS t36ete

FROM View1 AS t38
INNER JOIN View2 AS t36
ON t38.patient_id = t36.patient_id
AND t36.effective_time_start < t38.effective_time_start
JOIN (SELECT MAX(View1.effective_time_start) MaxDate,
         view1.paitent_id
  FROM View1
  INNER JOIN View2 
  ON View1.patient_id = View2.patient_id
  WHERE View2.effective_time_start < View1.effective_time_start
  GROUP BY View1.paitent_id) MaxDateCalc
ON MaxDateCalc.paitent_id = t38.paitent_id
and MaxDateCalc.MaxDate = t38.effective_time_start
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but in my testing it seems the only thing wrong with your 2nd query is the group by. In some basic temp tables i made i was getting the correct 1 row per and it was the max.

```
SELECT
  t38.patient_id,
  t38.id AS t38id,
  t38.effective_time_start AS t38ets,
  t38.effective_time_end AS t38ete,
  t36.id AS t36id,
  MAX(t36.effective_time_start) AS t36ets,
  t36.effective_time_end AS t36ete
FROM View1 AS t38
INNER JOIN View2 AS t36
  ON t38.patient_id = t36.patient_id
  AND t36.effective_time_start < t38.effective_time_start
GROUP BY t38.patient_id,
  t38.id AS t38id,
  t38.effective_time_start AS t38ets,
  t38.effective_time_end AS t38ete,
  t36.id AS t36id,
  t36.effective_time_end AS t36ete
```

Comment: If you use Group by ID, and still look for MAX date, you'll get the max date of each ID group, which will return every record.